# Blazor cannot find variables in related C# class file

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, maui-blazor

I have upgraded my Blazor project from .NET 6 to .NET 8.
After I have the issue, that my Blazor componennt cannot see the variables stored in related CS file:
[image]

But it is in the related CS file:
[image]

If I remove the partial keyword from class definition, it immediately writing error that partial keyword is missing.
If I create the variables directly into razor files @code{} block, it immediately writes the variables already defined:
[image]

Did any if you already met such issue?

Thanks!
G

Comment: Post code, errors and warnings as text, not images. Images can't be copied, compiled and tested

Comment: Do you get these errors after building? ASP.NET Core/Blazor Intellisense often gets confused

Comment: Yes. it's usually coming after build. Intellisense really sometimes making problems.

Comment: Try delete the `bin` and `obj` in your project folder and rebuild solution.

Comment: what happens if you add private/public infront of the attributes?

Comment: Does not change if I add public/private.  It seems the conversion from .NET 6 to .NET 8 was a problem. I created an other project natively with .NET 8, it does not have this problem. And has different structure.

Comment: Your public partial class `LoginComponent` should probably inherit from `ComponentBase`.

Comment: This is a VS tool issue or environment issue. I can create a new project and try to reproduce the issue, but it worked well on my side. You can try to clean the bin and obj file and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Put @ before _email. It should work.
If it doesn't then join the club :) VS 2022 on Blazor is full of idiosyncrasies like this. Check out the issue I have raised on GitHub:

https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/9696